# C# string.IndexOf() not working properly

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I am using XML-Like formatted file like:

```
<Tables>
    <Student>
      ID
      Roll_Number
      Name
    </Student>
</Tables>
```

I have read the file in a string and now for parsing, I want to use string.IndexOf(string) method. It works fine for the closing tags e.g `<Student>`, `<Tables>` but it is giving wrong indexes for closing tags e.g `</Tables>` or `</Students>`

Here is my code:

```
dbFileString.Substring(dbFileString.IndexOf("<Tables>") + "<Tables>".Length, dbFileString.IndexOf("</Tables>"));
```

Please help.

Comment: Please show the code you are using that contains the `IndexOf` we can't help you find your problem if you don't show us the code that contains the problem. Also, why are you using `IndexOf` at all and not one of the XML parsing classes built in to .NET?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the code won't be necessary as it is very basic, but as you requested, here it is:

dbFileString.Substring(dbFileString.IndexOf("<Student_Courses>") + "<Student_Courses>".Length, dbFileString.IndexOf("</Tables>"));

Comment: Are you trying to parse XML by hand?

Comment: Don't put code in comments, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36724347/edit) and put your code in there.

Comment: It is not XML, I just created Semi-XML sort of file just for my convenience and I want to parse it by hand.

Comment: Substring accepts an index and a length, not two indexes. The index returned is probably correct. It is just being used incorrectly.

Comment: @ZohaibAslam if you want to solve some problem you've created for yourself what is the point in asking others to solve it for you? It is very confusing what your actual goal is...

Comment: I would ask why you're using a "semi-xml" format and not just "XML"? Doing it this way might be more "convenient" (ie:faster) *now* but will likely lead to more difficult-to-maintain code in the future. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Mike I am glad you asked this. Actually it is not the requirement and it isn't going to be a long-term and thirdly I could have simply used comma delimited or any-delimited file for what I am doing, I used this structure for making it more readable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not `IndexOf` that is your problem, it is your use of `Substring`. The second parameter needs to be the length of the substring, not the ending index. You need to pass in "ending index - starting index" as the 2nd parameter.

```
var startingIndex = dbFileString.IndexOf("<Tables>") + "<Tables>".Length
var endingIndex = dbFileString.IndexOf("</Tables>")'
var result = dbFileString.Substring(startingIndex, endingIndex - startingIndex);
```

However, I really recommend you stop this approach of parsing XML by hand and using something like [`XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: Thank you Scott but I already clarified that it is not actually XML it is just kind of XML structure and I did it by choice. However, I know my mistake now. Yes it should be the length of string in second parameter. Working fine now!

Comment: @ZohaibAslam Clearly you should have read explanation of each method you've used (otherwise it would indicate that you did not put enough research in the question), so I have no idea how this good answer is useful to you... But since you've accepted it it means that you did not - and deserve good old downvote.

Comment: @AlexiLevenkov That's not a problem, actually I started programming in C# just today and even I did surfed all through the internet to know my mistake, I was too confused to realize this small silly mistake. And yes it happens if you have to surf internet for almost every method you use. So down votes, up votes, don't matter. Answer solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

dbFileString.Substring(int startIndex,int length) is the correct syntax. 
It would be helpful if you specified what you wanted to achieve here. 
As per the code I assume you are trying to trying to get the data between tags Tables and /Tables.
Kindly find the code below for it.

```
dbFileString.Substring(dbFileString.IndexOf("<Tables>")+"<Tables>".Length, dbFileString.Length-("</Tables>".Length) - ("Tables".Length));
```